# JavaFX ObjectOutputStream only returns null

Tags: java

I have encountered a weird behaviour of the `ObjectOutputStream` / `ObjectInputStream`.
I want to write a specific amount of Objects of the type `Sitzplatz` to the file `belegung`. So far so good. But if I try to read these Objects again they all just return `null`
Here is my Code:

```
public void getBelegtePlaetze() {
    if (belegung.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(belegung);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Sitzplatz platz = (Sitzplatz) ois.readObject();
            while (platz != null) {
                System.out.println(platz.getId());
                platz = (Sitzplatz) ois.readObject();
            }
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void speichereSitzplatzDaten() {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    if (!belegung.exists()) {
        try {
            belegung.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(belegung, true);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for (int i = 0; i < kundenListe.size(); i++) {
            Sitzplatz platz = kundenListe.get(i).getPlatz();
            platz.setId(Integer.toString(i));
            oos.writeObject(platz);
        }
        oos.writeObject(null); // Markiert EOF
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since I have already worked with me `ArrayList kundenListe` quite a bit in my program, I can be 100% sure that the data in it is properly set.
I have also already used the `ObjectOuputStream`in this program before and nearly copied the code, but still it does not work.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I've tried the suggestions from the comments, but I still have the same issues.
I have reduced the code to the little piece below, which should work 100%, since I have that code already in use in another class. No idea why it works in the other class and not in that one.

```
private File belegung = new File("belegung.kos");

public void getBelegtePlaetze() {

    if (belegung.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(belegung);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Pakett platz = (Pakett) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(platz.getId());
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void speichereSitzplatzDaten() {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    if (!belegung.exists()) {
        try {
            belegung.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(belegung);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        Pakett platz = new Pakett();
        platz.setId("test");
        oos.writeObject(platz);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of writing `oos.writeObject(null)` at the end, use `oos.flush()`

Comment: List is serializable, so you can serialize that instead.

Comment: `fos = new FileOutputStream(belegung, true);` Nope, that won't work. `ObjectOutputStream` writes a header to the output stream so you cannot simply append the data to a file. Otherwise a header will occur where `ObjectInputStream` does not expect it. Furthermore it would be more convenient to write the number of objects to the stream. Also consider using try-with-resources to close the streams.

Comment: @fabian I followed your hints and remove the append, but I still get `null`.
Can you also explain how to write the number of objects to the stream. Do you mean something like `writeInt()`?

Comment: Writing objects: `oos.writeInt(list.size()); for (Sitzplatz s : list) { oos.writeObject(s);}` reading objects: `int size = ois.readInt(); List<Sitzplatz> list = new ArrayList<>(size); for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { list.add((Sitzplatz) ois.readObject());}`